# MemoryError: Unable to allocate 3.78 GiB for an array with shape (802, 842, 1502) and data type float32

Tags: python, numpy, out-of-memory

I have results from a large simulation that I want to manipulate.

Now, it seems that it might be a bit too much for my computer to handle, as python stops and tells me:

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 3.78 GiB for an array with shape (802, 842, 1502)
```

and data type `float32`.

I do not manage to change /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory, as even with "sudo", the permission is denied.

So, I thought about reducing the precision of the numbers in the array, since the precision is important during the simulation to avoid accumulative errors, but less so afterwards.

Let's say the array is called `A`, I tried:

```
A = np.float16(A)
```

But obviously, to do that, you manipulate `A`, which is still in `float32`, and it raises the same error.

So...any better ideas?

Comment: If you're using a 64-bit OS, you may be able to put the array in a [numpy.memmap](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html). Memory-mapped files cannot be larger than 2GB on 32-bit systems.